# Created branch and submitted pull request using outdated fork. What now?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution, git-fork

I've forked a repo awhile back, recently created a new branch, made some changes, and submitted a pull request to the original repo. The problem is that before making changes I completely forgot to update my remote copy with the upstream repo (I thought that "Sync" in Github Desktop took care of this at the time)... So, now my changes are completely irrelevant and I'd like to start over.

I started by updating the master branch of my remote copy. But now I have a totally useless branch which is the one in the pull request.

What should I do without looking like more of a noob than now?

- Do I delete the branch, and start over by creating a new one? How will this affect the submitted PR?
- Do I update the branch with my updated master then deal with all the conflicts?
- Do I remove all the changes in my branch then start over?

I'd like to avoid creating more of a mess than present so detailed steps would be much appreciated in this case. I'm not too worried above having to start over if it will be a cleaner process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase your branch to upstream branch on which you want to build your PR (assuming master)

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git rebase upstream/master
```

Deal with all conflicts

Force-push your branch to origin

```
$ git push --force origin <branch name>
```

The PR will update itself.

Comment: Ah okay, so I think that is most similar to option 2. So how would this look in the PR? Will the previous commits disappear or another commit that reverts the previous?

Comment: After `$ git rebase upstream/master` I get `First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout` with some files and then `Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting` Do I just delete those files then?

Comment: You either discard your untracked files with `git clean -df` or commit them the standard way. When you have a clean head, do the rebase then.

The PR's old commits will disappear, if there were any comments on the old code, they will say "commented on an outdated diff".

Comment: I ended up using the `git clean` approach, rebased and everything is good now.